# Navigation In Ionic Angular.js

Tags: android, html, angularjs, cordova

I am new in ionic and I want to navigate my home URL to new URL in ionic blank application. Can you tell me how to achieve this.
here is my code:

```
app.service('sharedProperties', function () {
var userName= '',passWord='';
return {
setListName: function(user,pass) {
userName= user;
passWord= pass;
},
getStatus: function() {
if(userName=='feat',passWord=='password')
{
return succes;
}
}
};
});

app.controller("myNoteCtrl", function($scope,sharedProperties) {
$scope.save=function(parameter1,parameter2)
{
sharedProperties.setListName(parameter1,parameter2);
alert("Value Passed to Services");
}
$scope.getStat = function() {
$scope.msg = sharedProperties.getStatus();
}
});
app.js
var app = angular.module('myNoteApp', ['ionic', 'myNoteApp.controllers', 'myNoteApp.services']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are new in `angular.js` also.

You can use [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service for navigation.

### How to use

First add `$location` to your controller/factory/service parameter list. If you could not please follow this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Dependency-Injection) or [any link from Google](https://www.google.com.bd/?#q=angularjs+dependency+injection)

Then inside of your controller/factory/service use

`$location.path = '/home'`

if your current location is http://domainname.com/#/page1 it will be changed to http://domainname.com/#/home.

Comment: Probably you've pasted your code. Add a parameter `$location` then when you want to change the navigation set `$location.path = <Your Route>`

app.service('sharedProperties', function ($location) {
    var userName = '', passWord = '';
    return { setListName: function (user, pass) {
        userName = user;
        passWord = pass;
        console.log(userName);
        console.log(passWord);
    }, getStatus: function () {
        if (userName == 'feat', passWord == 'password') {
            $location.path = '/home';
        }
    } };
});

Answer (score 0):

**If you what to "redirect":**

In Ionic you might use:

```
$state.go('new.state')
```

Also $state should be injected to your controller.

**If you what other URL to be home:**

Then find in js/app.js, line like (for tabs template, not blank):

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');
```

/tab/dash - and set URL you what!

[More about](http://ionicframework.com/tutorials/intro-tutorial/)